# Whats the effect of COALESCE (a.id, a.id) in SQL?

Tags: sql

Has `COALESCE (a.id, a.id)` any effect beside renaming the column `a.id` to coalesce in SQL?

isn't `SELECT COALESCE(a.id, a.id) filled_id` equivalent to `SELECT a.id filled_id`?

I try to learn SQL and `COALESCE (a.id, a.id) filled_id` is in a solution of a task to COALESCE. I can't imagine any benefit of this.

Comment: Using the same value twice in `coalesce` does not really make sense. I would say it is a typo. Should probably be `COALESCE (a.id, b.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to `NULL`. For example,

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'third_value', 'fourth_value');
```

returns the third value because the third value is the first value that is not null.

So using the same value twice doesn't really make any sense